# Java REST service @delete object

Tags: java, rest, service, server

I have made a REST service which does all CRUD actions flawlessly except delete. When I process the delete request, everything is fine until the last element in the `ArrayList<User>`. When I remove the last one, I get back the 500 internal server error for some reason? When I put the constructor in `UserList` class to create default 2 users, it creates them successfully, and after I execute the delete request, I can delete one user. When I try to delete the last one remaining I get the 500 error, and when I try to list out all created users, somehow the constructor gets called again, and I have again those 2 default users?

Delete - serverside

```
@DELETE
@Path("/delete")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response deleteUser(String input) {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = null;

    try {
        obj = parser.parse(input);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

    String uName = (String) jsonObject.get("userName");

    try {
        uName = URLDecoder.decode(uName, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    returnAll = usrList.getUsers();
    if (userExists(uName)) {
        for (User u : returnAll) {
            if (u.getUserName().equals(uName)) {
                returnAll.remove(u);
            }
        }

        return Response.status(204).entity("User " + uName + " deleted...").build();
    } else
        return Response.status(400).entity("No such user...").build();

}
```

User List class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserList implements ListInterface {

    public UserList() {

        if (ListInterface.user.isEmpty()) {
            //populate list if empty

            User usr1 = new User();
            usr1.setUserName("No1");
            usr1.setFullName("Max Dax");
            ListInterface.user.add(usr1);

            User usr2 = new User();
            usr2.setUserName("MrX");
            usr2.setFullName("Ixs Oxs");
            ListInterface.user.add(usr2);
        }

    }

    public ArrayList<User> getUsers() {

        return ListInterface.user;
    }

}
```

List interface class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface ListInterface {

    public static ArrayList<User> user = new ArrayList<User>();
    public ArrayList<User> getUsers();


}
```

I connect through `http://localhost:8080/rest/user/delete` link, and in body I provide JSON `{"userName":"user"}` (I am using chrome advanced rest client for requests).

Comment: Add a `try{ ...}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}` around all the lines from `returnAll=...` until the last `return Response...400...`. You didn't include a few functions like userExists(), i guess you have a null pointer somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You manipulate the list that you are iterating on. If you catch the exception it will probably be easier to find the problem. But I think it is here:

```
for (User u : returnAll) {
        if (u.getUserName().equals(uName)) {
            returnAll.remove(u);
        }
    }
```

and it probably results in ConcurrentModificationException